# duplicate wordpress site on same bdd

Tags: phpmyadmin, duplicates

I have only one bdd with 2 wordpress sites :
first with _wp suffix 
second with _wp2 suffix.

For the url : 
mydomain/site1
mydomain/site2

Now i need to duplicate the site2 as site3 (mydomain/site3) and copy all data with _wp2 suffix and rename with _wp3 suffix.

Do you have a good method for that ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: There are plugins for that, also you could just copy the data + db and replace the suffix. What have you tried, where exactly are you failing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have only one db, i need to have tables with suffix _wp3 on the same db than tables _wp2 and _wp1.        And i need to copy data on ftp and change wp_config file with good suffix before or after add _wp3 suffix ?

Comment: Do you know a specific plugin for copy site ON THE SAME DB ? Thanks

Comment: I personally don't really know a plugin for test. But most of these "duplicate wordpress" or how they're called allow for this imo